# How to remove a row in Gridpane, JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I added nodes into Gridpane. Like this.

```
// These are ArrayList
FileName.add(new Label());
offset.add(new TextField());
volume.add(new Slider());
mute.add(new Button());
erase.add(new Button());

grid.add(FileName.get(nextIndex), 0, nextIndex, 1, 1);
grid.add(offset.get(nextIndex), 1, nextIndex, 1, 1);
grid.add(volume.get(nextIndex), 2, nextIndex, 1, 1);
grid.add(mute.get(nextIndex), 3, nextIndex, 1, 1);
grid.add(erase.get(nextIndex), 4, nextIndex, 1, 1);
```

And I want to remove a row from Gridpane, but if I remove all nodes in the row, row in GUI is removed, but row.getRowCount() didn't shrink.

I removed all nodes in the row.

```
// getRow() is GridPane.getRowIndex()
grid.getChildren().removeIf(n -> (getRow(n) == index));
```

In the GUI, the row seems to be removed, but if I run getRowCount(), didn't shrink

---

Comment: Do you really need to do more? The empty row shouldn’t be taking up any space, and if you add further rows you still want their indexes to be adding with an index greater than the row indexes of anything that’s there. If you really do need to, you would have to reduce by one the row index of all nodes in a row greater than the one you removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for posting comments. I tried not removing GridPane and list, and it launched correctly!

I think these comments should be answers, so I copy the comments.

James's comment ↓

> Do you really need to do more? The empty row shouldn’t be taking up any space, and if you add further rows you still want their indexes to be adding with an index greater than the row indexes of anything that’s there. If you really do need to, you would have to reduce by one the row index of all nodes in a row greater than the one you removed.

jewelsea's comment ↓

> To understand James comment, look at the way GridPane.getRowCount() works. It counts the number of row constraints, then it looks at the row indexes of all the current children of the pane and returns the max(numRowConstraints, maxRowIndex). To reduce the row count, you need to reindex your rows manually and ensure that you have no unnecessary row constraints for rows no longer in the pane.

Comment: Perhaps, if you really want dynamic content, then a GridPane isn't the correct layout container.  Maybe a TableView would be better, and style it to remove the headings and borders.

Comment: Also, consider a [`GridView`](https://controlsfx.github.io/javadoc/11.1.0/org.controlsfx.controls/org/controlsfx/control/GridView.html) or [`SpreadSheetView`](https://controlsfx.github.io/javadoc/11.1.0/org.controlsfx.controls/org/controlsfx/control/spreadsheet/SpreadsheetView.html) from ControlsFX. I'd advise looking into those first before attempting to highly customize a `TableView` (as that can be a bit tricky and error-prone unless you really know what you are doing).  But perhaps just sticking with a simple GridPane with the suggested comments in the answer will be sufficient for you.